# ERROR: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myHttpConnectionManager' while setting bean property 'clientConnectionManager'

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am doing camel migration from 2.25.4 to 3.0.24. WHile doing this I have to do some chnages in camel config xml file where **httpConnectionManager** has been updated to **clientConnectionManager** for bean class org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent.

Here below I have mentioned piece of my camel config xml file:

```
 <bean id="http" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
     <property name="camelContext" ref="camel"/>
     <property name="clientConnectionManager" ref="myHttpConnectionManager"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="https" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
     <property name="camelContext" ref="camel"/>
     <property name="clientConnectionManager" ref="myHttpConnectionManager"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="myHttpConnectionManager" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
     <property name="params" ref="myHttpConnectionManagerParams"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="myHttpConnectionManagerParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams">
     <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="20"/>
 </bean>
```

With this change, when I start tomcat, it gives me below error:

```
11-May-2023 11:07:16.052 SEVERE [main] 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'http' 
defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/camel-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert 
property value of type 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager' to 
required type 'org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager' for property 
'clientConnectionManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert 
value of type 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager' to required type 
'org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager' for property 'clientConnectionManager': no 
matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Is there any specific version of apache commons-httpclient requirement with camel 3.20.4? Or instead of MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager, I have to use some other class?